# Need Regex pattern to extract xml request and responses from log file

Tags: php, xml

I have a log file with multiple xml requests and responses.  I need to parse each set request/responses.  With my limited regex experience, I have been trying to come up with a regex pattern to parse each set of request/response using https://regex101.com/ but I have am having no luck and decided I need to ask for some help.

I am working on a Linux PHP 7.1.

My xml log files looks like this:
         `

```
***********************************************************************
API Client Address: 1.1.1.1
Begin API Request: 7/18/2019 11:45:42 AM
content-length:xxx

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MYXML>
  <header/>
  <body>
    <data_block>      
    </data_block>
  </body>
</MYXML>


************************************************************************
End API Response: 7/1/2019 10:17:06 AM
Content-Length: 502

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MYXML>
    <header></header>
    <body>
        <data_block>            
        </data_block>
    </body>
</MYXML>

************************************************************************
API Client Address: 1.1.1.1
Begin API Request: 7/18/2019 11:45:42 AM
content-length:xxx

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MYXML>
  <header/>
  <body>
    <data_block>      
    </data_block>
  </body>
</MYXML>


************************************************************************
End API Response: 7/1/2019 10:17:06 AM
Content-Length: 502

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MYXML>
    <header></header>
    <body>
        <data_block>            
        </data_block>
    </body>
</MYXML>

************************************************************************
API Client Address: 1.1.1.1
Begin API Request: 7/18/2019 11:45:42 AM
content-length:xxx

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MYXML>
  <header/>
  <body>
    <data_block>      
    </data_block>
  </body>
</MYXML>


************************************************************************
End API Response: 7/1/2019 10:17:06 AM
Content-Length: 502

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MYXML>
    <header></header>
    <body>
        <data_block>            
        </data_block>
    </body>
</MYXML>
```

`

I need each group of request/response to be extracted so I can parse each group testing the response to see if an error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex to do this.  You can use basic string operations like strtok() (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) to tokenize the responses into an array.  Then you can parse the XML from each response.

Another string operation you could use is: explode()
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Oh, and I assume you don't want to spend time writing an XML parser. Google for information or a library on parsing XML in PHP.  There's no point in reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

From your file, you might extract the xml parts using an expression like:

```
^<\?xml version="1.0"\?>(?:\r?\n(?!</MYXML>).*)*\r?\n</MYXML>$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zErj6Y/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/BEqaG)

From the matches you can extract those parts and use [simplexml_load_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) or use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) with for example [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to get your values.

For example:

```
$str = "...";
$re = '~^<\?xml version="1.0"\?>(?:\r?\n(?!</MYXML>).*)*\r?\n</MYXML>$~m';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($match);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $val = $xpath->query("/MYXML/body/data_block")->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $val . PHP_EOL;
}
```